# Why would extending JerseyTest vs extending TestCase cause no tests to be found

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven-2, junit, jersey

I am attempting to get the Jersey test framework working.  We are building using maven 1.x.  I've created the following testcase...

```
public class SomeResourceTest extends JerseyTest
{
    public SomeResourceTest () throws Exception 
    {
        super(new WebAppDescriptor.Builder(PACKAGE_NAME)
                      .contextPath(PATH).build());
    }    
    @Test
    public void testSomething() 
    {
        Assert.assertEquals(true, true);
    }
}
```

When I build, I get no tests found in SomeResourceTest.

Now, when I change the testcase to extend `junit.framework.TestCase`, the test runs just fine.

Any clue what might be causing the problem? `JerseyTest` is supposed to extend `TestCase`, so I am assuming it to be some other configuration problem.

Comment: Perhaps you need a "JerseyTest" plugin for maven?

Comment: You may want to add the junit tag to this question so more test folks see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any clue what might be causing the problem? JerseyTest is supposed to extend TestCase (...)

The Jersey Test Framework is [build over JUnit 4.x](http://blogs.oracle.com/naresh/entry/jersey_test_framework_makes_it) so, no, it doesn't.

To run JUnit 4.x tests with Maven 1.x, you'll have to:

- Add Junit 4.X in your dependencies
- Use the JUnit4TestAdapter in your test classes:

  ```
  /**
   * @return instance of this as Junit test case
   */
  public static junit.framework.Test suite()
  {
      return new JUnit4TestAdapter(MyTestClass.class);
  }
  ```
- Use a JDK 5+

See http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MPTEST-65.

Comment: This worked, along with upping my Jersey jars to the latest.  I think I had some combination of Junit 3.x, and a motely Jersey collection. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What version of JerseyTest are you using?  The latest version relies on JUnit 4 and does not extend TestCase.

Also, your test is a bit confusing.  It has @Test which implies you are using JUnit 4 and shouldn't extend TestCase.  But it sounds like you are still relying on the testXXX and TestCase subclass convention from JUnit 3.8 in your description.